# Regular Expressions with at least 3 b's and at most 2 a's

Tags: regular-expressions

I am not a Regular Experssion expert, but my request is simple: I need to match any string that has at least 3 characters of B and at most 2 characters of A

so for example:

```
"ABABBB"  => Accepted
"ABBBBBB" => Accepted
"BBB"     => Accepted
"ABB"     => Rejected
"AABB"    => Rejected
"AA"      => Rejected
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Please don't delete your question after receiving an answer.  Part of our mission here is to build up an archive of questions and answers that will be useful not only to you but to others in the future as well.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72582274/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/152257/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any simple solution.

There are 15 ways to write a word with 3 $b$'s and at most 2 $a$'s:
$bbb$, $abbb$, $babb$, $bbab$, $bbba$, $aabbb$, $ababb$, $abbab$, $abbba$, $baabb$, $babab$, $babba$, $bbaab$, $bbaba$ and $bbbaa$.

Between every pair of letters of those words, you can insert any number of $b$'s, which can be written with a $b^*$ in a regular expression.

So you'd get:
$$bbbb^* + b^*abbbb^* + b^*babbb^*+ … + b^*ab^*abbbb^* + …$$

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression can be developed from the following finite state machine for at most 2 **A**s and at least 3 **B**s by using all possible paths separate by |, and using * where their is a loop edge.

[image: Finite State Machine]

Resulting regex: `AABBBB*|ABABBB*|ABBABB*|ABBBAB*|ABBBB*AB*|BAABBB*|BABABB*|BABBAB*|BABBB*AB*|BBAABB*|BBABAB*|BBABB*AB*|ABBBB*|BABBB*|BBABB*|BBBAB*|BBBB*(AB*)?(AB*)?`